# Excel VBA - Updating time in a Datetime formatted cell with 6AM

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I'm having trouble modifying the time to a specific time in a cell with both *date and time* with VBA.

The cell is formatted as "d/mm/yyyy h:mm AM/PM" and I'm taking a cell with *time only* in it formatted "h:mm AM/PM" and trying to use this bit of code to update the time portion (t1 is used thoughout the rest of the sub..)

```
Public t1 As String

t1 = Range("H1").Value
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell = DateValue(ActiveCell) & " " & TimeValue(t1)
```

This seems to work on and off.. 6AM for instance will update the time to 12:25, and 10AM flat-out wont work at all. I figure I'm just doing something wrong but I've searched up and down for this and it seems like it's not a common problem.. Does anyone have any better ideas?! This is driving me nuts

The value in cell H1 does change, so i do need to pull the value from that in one way or another.

Comment: can you add date and time, like `ActiveCell = DateValue(ActiveCell) + TimeValue(t1)` ?

Comment: doesn't appear so.. I get a 'Type mismatch' error

Comment: You'll get a type mismatch from if ActiveCell or T1 cannot be converted to dateValue or TimeValue respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned the cell formatting; note that the cell formatting doesn't matter when you are merely retrieving the value as in: `dt = ActiveCell`

Note also that it is possible to store a date as text `=istext(H1)` returns true. In this case changing the formatting won't make any difference. Or you can store it as a value in the usual fashion. `=isNumber(H1)` returns true. Either way won't make any difference when using `DateValue("H1")`

I suggest declaring dt and tm as dates so that if the assignment `dt = Range("H1").Value` succeeds you know you actually have a date. Then you won't get a mismatch error when adding the dateValue + timeValue.

Try this

```
Dim dt As Date
Dim tm as Date
dt = Range("H1").Value
tm = ActiveCell.value
Range("D3").value = DateValue(dt) + TimeValue(tm) 'returns a date/time as a value
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks! I just changed the values for dt and tm around to set the timeValue from H1 rather than the date. (extra thanks for examples on the formatting too, appreciate the extra detail)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
t1 = Range("H1").Value
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell + t1
End Sub
```